# JSON Object many errors. Help out

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

[image: Updated code][image: Code error 2]I have made a JSON object and getting so many errors. I am new to JSON so kindly help. Posting here with the screenshots. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
[![var data\[\]= {"cars": 
        "Honda":\[
            {"model":"Figo" },
            {"model":"City"}
        \],
        "Audi": \[
            {"model":"A6"},
            {"model":"A8"}
        \]
    }

data.cars\['Honda'\]\[0\].model   
data.cars\['Honda'\]\[1\].model   
data.cars\['Audi'\]\[0\].model 
ata.cars\['Audi'\]\[1\].model 

for (var make in data.cars) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.cars\[make\].length; i++) {
        var model = data.cars\[make\]\[i\].model;

        alert(make + ', ' + model);
    }
}][1]][1]
```

[image: Error screen]

Using JSONformatter and validator site for checking my code.

Comment: how do you generate your json data?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Could you please elaborate what you means by generating the json data. Do not mind if it is too basic to ask as I am totally novice for JSON. I just wanted to make a JSON object with few of the car models. and want to pass them through AJAX but here my JSON object itself is showing so many errors. And I am not getting how to resolve them. Thank you.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp, try to read on json, and you can make use of this link to validate your json data http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned

> I am totally novice for JSON

I would like to explain you this completely.

There are little bit of syntax errors in the way you are doing this. You are actually doing a for loop inside a javascript object which will obviously break. If your intention is to alert all the models of all the make, then here is how you do it..

initially you have this

```
var data = {
            cars:{
                  "Honda":
                   [
                    {"model":"Figo" },
                    {"model":"City"}
                   ],
                  "Audi":
                   [
                    {"model":"A6"},
                    {"model":"A8"}
                   ]
                 }
           }
```

You have a variable called `data` which is a object (`{}` refers to object) and this object has a property called `cars` and this property holds a object(`{}` refers to object). Now this object has 2 properties `Honda` and `Audi`. Each of this properties are of type array (`[]` refers to array). And this each array further contains list of objects.

So once you are clear with the above point. Let manipulate the object you have.

Do a forloop to get all the properties of the `cars` object and when we have hold of each property lets loop its array and then extract the `model` property value.

```
for (var make in data.cars) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.cars[make].length; i++) {
     var model = data.cars[make][i].model;    
     alert(make + ', ' + model);
  }
}
```

Also dont get confused with Javascript Object and JSON....

In the above example the variable `data` is Javascript Object and when you do `JSON.strinfigy(data)` you are converting this Javascript object into string format and that string format is called JSON...

A **[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6yw1tdwh/)**  to help you understand better.

Comment: Thanks alot for making the things clear to me. But again JSON formatter is not accepting it and showing the error only..

Comment: @stackwitharray JSON formatter will not accept it because its not a JSON at all... Its javascript object (the result after parsing a valid JSON is javascript object)

Comment: var jsonString=JSON.stgingify(data); Where will I declare this var. ?

Comment: the line of code you provided is absolutely fine.  What do you mean where do you declare? I didnt get you.  Also after converting your object to string this is what I get `"{"cars":{"Honda":[{"model":"Figo"},{"model":"City"}],"Audi":[{"model":"A6"},{"model":"A8"}]}}"` paste this in any json formatter and you will see valid results

Comment: You are absolutely right that this is the right code but my concern is to print them too by making it as JSON OBJECT and for fetching the values I will have to write a for loop and there I am getting errors ab shown by me. Okay so could you please tell me the exact code by which i get the car models with json object and loop? Thanks. I got little bit confused.

Comment: @stackwitharray that is exactly what I have showed you in my answer right? I am confused now :) .. ok If at all you have a JSON do `JSON.parse(yourdata)` to convert that Json into a object and then do the forloop as mentioned above in the answer

Comment: Now I am not able to add the screenshot but I am getting error and I am sure that its the silly error. If you don't mind sharing your Skype Id so that could show you via a call so it would resolve my things as I need to complete it soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109509/discussion-between-reddy-and-stackwitharray).

Answer (score 0):

Imho it's more like :

```
var cars = {
      "Honda":
      [
         {"model":"Figo" },
         {"model":"City"}
      ],
      "Audi":
      [
         {"model":"A6"},
         {"model":"A8"}
      ]
   }
```

If you want a huge JSON object storing many cars attributes arrays.
Why do you use these "/" everywhere ?

(PS : if you wanna see some examples -> http://json.org/example.html)

Comment: {
    "cars": 
        "Honda" { 
            "model":"Figo" ,
            "model":"City"
        }
        ,
        "Audi": {
            "model":"A6",
            "model":"A8"
        }

JSON_data.cars["Honda"][0].model   
JSON_data.cars["Honda"][1].model   
JSON_data.cars["Audi"][0].model 
JSON_data.cars["Audi"][1].model 

for (var make in data.cars) {
    for (var i = 0; i < JSON_data.cars[make].length; i++) {
        var model = JSON_data.cars[make][i].model;
       
        alert(make + ', ' + model);
    }
} how will i get the value of index 0 n 1 . could you please show me entire code

Comment: I added the updated code in my question and now please help me that what object and how i should make an object to call the diferent array elements. how will i get the value of index 0 n 1 . could you please show me entire code. Thank you .

Comment: Note that your `cars` is not a JSON, it is a javacript object. JSON is the string version of this javascript object.

Comment: Yes, @Reddy, you're totally right ! (and I +1 your comment for this reason cause actually the difference can be important).

Comment: Well @stackwitharray, you have a string representing a JSON serialized JS object. Before being able to loop and doin' something in its properties you need to "deserialize" it back to a classical JS object. And then make a for loop to find what you're searching for. Or maybe use IndexOf().

Comment: Thank you@Reddy . And if it is a Javascript object then how can i make a JSON object?

Comment: With JSON.stringify() : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Error:Expecting object or array, not string..... Why am I getting this error. I from my side am making an object only but it is treating it as a var.

Comment: Can you re-post your code with changes please ? Cause I think many lines has been changed and it's hard to say from where the error comes without that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the structure your looking for:

```
cars={
    make:{
        honda:[
            {
                model:"accord",
                color:"black",
                cylinders: "6",
                year:"2012"
            },
            {
                model:"civic",
                color:"white",
                cylinders: "4",
                year:"2015"
            }
        ],
        acura:[
            {
                model:"integra",
                color:"red",
                cylinders: "4",
                year:"1992"
            },
            {
                model:"RSX",
                color:"Metallic Blue",
                cylinders: "4",
                year:"2016"
            }               
        ],
        audi:[
            {
                model:"R8",
                color:"white",
                cylinders: "8",
                year:"2015"
            },
            {
                model:"A8",
                color:"red",
                cylinders: "8",
                year:"2016"
            }               

        ]
    }
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
    var models=[],colors=[],cylinder=[],year=[]; //INSTANTIATE ARRAYS
    for(p in cars.make){ //LOOP THROUGH OBJECT PROPS (CARS.MAKE)
        cars.make[p].forEach((o)=>{ //LOOP THROUGH (CARS.CARS.PROPS) PUSH OBJ INTO ARRAYS
            models.push(o.model);  
            colors.push(o.color);
            cylinders.push(o.cylinders);
            year.push(o.year);
        });
    console.log(models);
    console.log(colors);
    console.log(cylinders);
    console.log(year);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying sir. But what I want is that I want to fetch the array elements too. See the latest code which i just gave in my question. Here you are just giving the array elements. Isn't it possible to fetch the array elements ? The thing which I am doing is the wrong way or what? Thanks :)

Comment: @stackwitharray yea your JSON array isn't structured right, that first thing got to fix, just look at my example syntax above. but YES, to answer you question you can def get the get whatever `prop:vals` you want. What specifically are you looking to get `models`?

Comment: Yes i want to fetch the models of both of the car brands which i have specified here

Comment: Thank you but this "car" would not be treated as a json object but as a javascript object. So how will we make it as a json object ?

Comment: @stackwitharray I think your getting confuse, JSON (Java-Script-Object-Notation) is a javascript object.

Comment: Thank you. But did you run it in any JSON formatter ? https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ try it in this one. and see the very first error.. Which is one of my main concern :)

Comment: @stackwitharray I'm console.logging it and my output is fine I've tested it multiple times, I wouldn't use some site just log it in your browser